# Iterate over list produced with levelsof

Tags: stata

The example below reproduces my problem. There is a string variable which takes several values. I want to create a global list and iterate over it in a loop. But it does not work. I've tried several versions without success. Here is the example code:

```
webuse auto, clear
levelsof make // list of car makes
global MAKE r(levels) // save levels in global list

foreach i in $MAKE { // loop some command over saved list 
    sum if make == "`$MAKE'"  // ERROR 198, invalid 'Concord' 
}
```

Using "`$MAKE'" or $MAKE does not yield desired output.

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Normally, for lists to work, they should be saved as in `A B C D [...]`. In my case, `levelsof` produces a list of the following kind:

```
di $MAKE
`"AMC Concord"' `"AMC Pacer"' `"AMC Spirit"' `"Audi 5000"' `"Audi Fox"' `"BMW 320i"' [...]
```

So clearly not what is needed. But not sure how to get what I need.

Comment: As pointed out by @TheIceBear you need an equals sign in your `global` definition.  The code would not have worked without it. The nesting of a global macro reference within a local macro reference would work if and only if the global contained the name of a local macro, which is not impossible but not at all what you have. In essence use `$` to get the contents of a global macro and single quotation marks to get the contents of a local macro, but keep the syntax separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. Note that I am using a `local` instead of a `global`. The difference is only scope. Only use `global` if you need to reference the value across do-files. You can remove the `display` lines below.

```
*Sysuse reads this data from disk, it comes with all Stata installations
sysuse auto, clear

*Use levelsof, and assign the returned r(levels) using a = to the local
levelsof make
local all_makes = r(levels)

*Loop over the local like this. Note that foreach creates a local, in this
*case called this_make that stores the elements in the local one per iteration
foreach this_make of local all_makes { 
    display "`this_make'"
    sum if make == "`this_make'"
}
```

If global is what you need, then you simply change it to this:

```
*Sysuse reads this data from disk, it comes with all Stata installations
sysuse auto, clear

*Use levelsof, and assign the returned r(levels) using a = to the global
levelsof make
global all_makes = r(levels)

*Loop over the global like this. Note that foreach creates a local, in this
*case called this_make that stores the elements in the global one per iteration
foreach this_make of global all_makes { 
    display "`this_make'"
    sum if make == "`this_make'"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! So essentially, in the loop, instead of using `in` I had to use `of global`? Ah, and some other edits. It works. Thanks!!

Comment: That wasn’t your mistake. The statement inside the loop was confused. You needed to refer to local macro i.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fine accepted answer but plenty more can be said. See for example [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/).

I am positive about `levelsof` as its original author, but for the purpose specified, to loop over the levels of a variable, it can be a lot cleaner to use `egen, group()` and loop over the integer levels of that variable. See the FAQ just linked for more. The example in the original question is a case in point, as looping over distinct string values can be tricky with a need to use double quotes `" "` and to watch out for spaces and so forth.

The underlying problem is not revealed but an extra  comment is to underline that `by:` and its sibling commands such as `statsby` or  commands similar in spirit such as `rangestat` from SSC offer, in effect, looping without looping.